# "Not well formed JSON stream" when using moveto or copyto on file from SharePoint 2013 REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to enable file move and copy operations on files in a sharepoint 2013 document library. I have the list and delete operations working but when I try to call /moveto(newfile=...,flags=1) or /copyto(strnewfile,boverwrite=true) I get an error "Not well formed JSON stream".

I have tried the newurl (or strnewurl) both with and without the site prefix (e.g. /sites/dev). I have separately verified that getfilebyserverrelativeurl is in fact returning the file.

Has anyone run into this before?

```
function copyFile() {
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web" +
            "/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/dev/Sample1/Customer.dim')" +
            "/copyto(strnewurl='/Sample1/filename.docx',boverwrite=false)" +
            "?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "IF-MATCH": "*"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: errorHandler
    });
}

function moveFile() {
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web" +
            "/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/dev/Sample1/Customer.dim')" +
            "/moveto(newurl='/Sample1/filename.docx',flags=1)" +
            "?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: errorHandler
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem. My solution was to use ajax instead of the executor:

```html
$.ajax({
  url: SPAppWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + file + "')/copyto(strnewurl='" + target + "',boverwrite=false)?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "IF-MATCH": "*",
    "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
  },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

Strange enough when I use the same with the RequestExecutor it doesn't work.

Comment: I thought the point of the RequestExecutor was for cross domain requests... I think if it is on the same domain then ajax should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the copyto URL parameter needs to be server relative, not site relative. So 
    `strnewurl='/sites/dev/Sample1/filename.docx'`
instead of
    `strnewurl='/Sample1/filename.docx'`

I know all the docs say it's site relative, but this is what's worked for me. I also only include the accept header.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint Online working url
/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/test/Template.xlsx')/copyTo(strNewUrl='/sites/test/Exports/Template_copy_5.xlsx',bOverWrite=true)